# Should a question that's good but in reality off topic, be down voted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, off-topic

It's a conundrum. It's not a good question for SO? So yes down vote it. But on the other hand it might actually be a very well written question just on the wrong SE site.

Comment: Do you go to a lawyer if you want medical advice?  In case of off topic, quality is not important. (You can flag for a migration if there is a suitable SE site).

Comment: It should be downvoted, the asker should be tracked down and beaten, and then someone who is a real meanie should kick their dog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's better to vote for migration or vote to close than downvote. But downvote is also a good way to show that we don't want anymore such question here. Downvoted questions are ignored by community, so as to discourage other users to ask similar questions.

Although I rarely downvotes any such question, but it's my personal preference. What is wrong and what is right is decided by the community. So if they want to downvote, it's not wrong.

Comment: Also: Downvotes get nullified at migration.

Comment: @Dennis I didn't know that part. It's actually a good feature.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that you can vote to close a question and move it to another site. I think a vote up and a vote to close can sometimes be appropriate.